# How to Calculate 95 % CI and P value for Geometric Mean and SD in R programming

Tags: r

I am new to R programming. I would like to calculate 95 % CI and Pvalue for Geometric Mean Geometric SD in R programming. I have used the below code.

`center <- 30`
`stddev <- 5`
`n<- 10`
`error <- qt(0.975, df=n-1)*stddev/sqrt(n)`
`lower_bound <- center - error`
`upper_bound <- center + error`

I am getting different value when comparing with other statistical application. So is it correct or not.

Comment: Could you give more details about the differences with the other statistical application and what the other statistical application is? Also, have you checked out the following post? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285173/how-to-calculate-confidence-interval-for-a-geometric-mean

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the 95% CI values and matching with other application also. I have used Gmean function.     But to calculate Pvalue which test to be applied for Geometric Mean and Geometric SD. I have applied Ttest to calculate pvalue. Is it correct?

Comment: The p-value and the 95% CI are "equivalent" quantities: if you use a method to compute the 95% CI and you think it's the most appropriate method, the same method can be used to compute the p-value. In fact, the probability of observing a value outside the 95% CI is equal to 5% and that's precisely the p-value that can be associated to the CI border values.

Comment: Thankyou Mastropi for your response. Now it is clear.

Comment: But in Gmean function, there is no option to add 'Group_by' function or grouping the variables. How to add by or grouping . My code is -Gmean(data$age,method=c("classic"),conf.level = 0.95,sides="two.sided",na.rm = T). I want CI for gender wise & Race wise.  Could you please suggest how to do it.

Comment: Look at the `group_by()` function in package `dplyr`. With this function you can do any processing by groups, in this case by gender and race.